# How to copy/paste a text-box from a Word document to a PDF file?

Tags: windows, acrobat

I have a problem with copy/paste text-boxes from a Word document to a PDF file. I have the text-box already made in my Word document with specific colour, text-size, 
 etc.
When I try to copy it and paste it in a PDF it just turns to an image, so i cannot add any changes on the text which is already inside the box. Is there a way to get the text-box in the PDF file as a text-box and not as an image?

Answer (score 0):

No need to copy the text-box element over. Just export the Word Document as a PDF and open into Acrobat.

If you're struggling to edit files, check your acrobat package is supported to allow you to modify .pdf's? If you are just using Adobe Acrobat Reader this would cause this issue, you would need Adobe Acrobat Pro.

Hope I'm of help

-Stuart